# How can I see how many people viewed a specific question?

Tags: support

I am interested in finding out how many peopele viewed a specific question. How can I do that?

I noticed that the number of views is displayed when going through the
["questions tag"](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions).

However, I am interested in a question which I can only find by "search" (not by sliding through the "questions"-pages). When the question is presented after using the search option, the number of views is no longer available.

Is there an easy way around this? (I do not want to blindly slide through all the pages to find the question...)

Does it help if it's a question I asked?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no way to see how many people viewed a particular post -- rather only a viewcount is shown. When the same person reloads the page after a certain time (15 minutes?), then this is counted again.

Comment: OK, is there a way to view the viewcount then? (not from the main questions-page).

Comment: @j.c. Yes, thanks. I missed this somehow... BTW If I understood Stefan's comment correctly this number does include several views by the same person/user/IP address, right?

Comment: I made my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the right of each question page, right above "Featured on Meta / Hot Meta Posts" there is text giving when the question was asked and how many times it was viewed.

The viewcount is discussed in [this meta stackexchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated) but so far as I can tell the details of how it really works have not been divulged officially. As Stefan Kohl points out above, it does seem to include views by the same person; it would probably be impossible / infeasible to figure out how many views of each page were actually by unique "individuals", see the previous link.